# javascript contentWidth didn't fire event listener after open other page inside iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

Alright, I think it's hard to write my trouble here,

so, please visit : [test iframe contentWidth](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?)

And then just replace those code with these :

```
<script>
document.getElementById("myFrame").contentWindow.onclick = test;
function test() {
  var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
  var elmnt = iframe.contentWindow;
  elmnt.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
</script>
```

And then click the on the iframe to change it background color.

These code runs well when I clicked on iframe once, but after I clicked another link page eg : **Learn HTML**

these code didn't work. it looks if iframe / browser unable to caught event (onclick).

**Q** : How to fix so that event still able to catch by contentWidth , though user click another link page?

please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Your link doesn't work.

Comment: If you press Ctrl+M while editing your post, you will be eble to paste your js/html/css to demonstrate the issue.